# Eclipse encoding

Tags: java, eclipse, encoding, utf-8

I set my eclipse default encoding by trying:
Windows > Preferences > General > Content Types, set UTF-8 as the default encoding for all content types.
Windows > Preferences > General > Workspaces, set "Text file encoding" to "Other : UTF-8".

Then we I import some projects, it always mess up some characters:

```
                    case 'a':
        case 'e':
        case 'i':
        case 'o':
        case 'u':
        case 'y':
        case '�':
        case '�':
        case '�':
        case '�':
        case '�':
        case '�':
        case '�':
        case '�':
        case '�':
        case '�':
        case '�':
        case '�':
    }
```

What should I do? Any ideas?

Comment: Does the Text font you have selected in Eclipse support these characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things maybe happening:

1. Some projects (even folders and/or files) may have their own specific charset which could be different to the whole workspace-level charset preference. You could right-click on the specific file and do Properties -> Resource to check which text file encoding is really being used (**Default** computed or **Other**). As additional info, this Resource specific preferences are stored in the **./settings/org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs** file of the project.
2. If the computed charset is UTF-8, the file you are viewing in the Java editor is not really coded in UTF-8. To verify that, you could check those characters in a [hexadecimal editor](http://goo.gl/ggoIQN), and use this useful **[UTF-8 table](http://home.telfort.nl/~t876506/utf8tbl.html)** to compare the expected UTF=8 hex value in the table and the actual value the hex editor shows you it has.

Comment: I messed up the encoding settings, and I installed the eclipse again. It is fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to change the .java file encoding from Eclipse (right click on the .java file -> Properties -> Resource -> Text file encoding)?