# Error Invalid character constant

Tags: android, character-arrays

problem in declaring this

```
char strFrench[]    = {'Ã¨', 'Ã©', 'Ãª', 'Ã«', 'Ãº', 'Ã»', 'Ã¹', 'Ã¼', 'Ã¯', 'Ã®', 'Ã ', 'Ã¢', 'Ã´', 'Ã¶', 'Ã§', 'Ã¿', 'Ãˆ', 'Ã‰', 'ÃŠ', 'Ã‹', 'Ãš', 'Ã›', 'Ã™', 'Ãœ', 'Ã�', 'ÃŽ',
                    'Ã€', 'Ã‚', 'Ã”', 'Ã–', 'Ã‡', 'ÂŸ', 'Ã ', 'Ã¢', '-'};
```

getting invalid character constant.for every character how to fix this?
here is my total code

```
    char strFrench[]    = {'Ã¨', 'Ã©', 'Ãª', 'Ã«', 'Ãº', 'Ã»', 'Ã¹', 'Ã¼', 'Ã¯', 'Ã®', 'Ã ', 'Ã¢', 'Ã´', 'Ã¶', 'Ã§', 'Ã¿', 'Ãˆ', 'Ã‰', 'ÃŠ', 'Ã‹', 'Ãš', 'Ã›', 'Ã™', 'Ãœ', 'Ã�', 'ÃŽ',
                'Ã€', 'Ã‚', 'Ã”', 'Ã–', 'Ã‡', 'ÂŸ', 'Ã ', 'Ã¢', '-' /*, ''', 'Å“', 'Å’'*/};
        char strEnglish[]   = {'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'i', 'i', 'a', 'a', 'o', 'o', 'c', 'y', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'U', 'U', 'U', 'U', 'I', 'I',
                'A', 'A', 'O', 'O', 'c', 'y', 'a', 'a',  ' ' /*, ' ', 'oe', 'oe'*/};


        String str = getValidString(strFrench, strEnglish, searchKey);
        str.replaceAll("'", " ");           
        str.replaceAll("oe", "Å“");
        str.replaceAll("oe", "'Å’");
        ville = mDbHelper.getVilleInfo(str.toString());
```

Comment: You may need to use proper encoding to compile java files. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18936884/eclipse-encoding

Answer (score 1):

You can't store multiple characters as a single char.

If you want to use multiple characters in one element, then use a String array:

```
String[] strFrench = {"Ã¨", "Ã©", "Ãª", "Ã«", "Ãº", "Ã»", "Ã¹", "Ã¼", "Ã¯", 
        "Ã®", "Ã ", "Ã¢", "Ã´", "Ã¶", "Ã§", "Ã¿", "Ãˆ", "Ã‰", "ÃŠ", "Ã‹", "Ãš",
        "Ã›", "Ã™", "Ãœ", "Ã�", "ÃŽ", "Ã€", "Ã‚", "Ã”", "Ã–", "Ã‡", "ÂŸ", "Ã ",
        "Ã¢", "-"};
```

Comment: Actually they look like characters but encoded in UTF-16 (2 bytes per char). EDITED: Probably it's UTF-8

Comment: it happened bcz i am using code which is written in linux ,previously it is working fine .when import my project on windows i got this issue